# Mass adding new tags in GTM

Tags: json, import, google-tag-manager, edit, xls

Often I have to **add many similar** UA-tags in **GTM** with new triggers. Except general properties difference only in 3-5 values. I guess to do it **comfortably and FASTER** will in **exporting json** into xls(xlsx) **and back** after adding/editing what I need. But I've not find any decision nowhere.

Are anybody knows how to take it to be done?
Python-script, web-app, application in google sheets, anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, while there are UI tools to import and export containers, this isn’t something that the API offers, so you can't do it programmatically.

Comment: I mean just to re-build exported json-file into xls, edit it there and save back to json to import to GTM